# How to remove JSON header using shell script?

Tags: json, shell, unix, curl

We are getting JSON data using `curl` and data is getting appended to the same file by calling endpoint URL using `curl` in a loop.

Due to this, header of JSON output is being repetitive in same file. so I want to remove multiple headers from file except the first one using shell.

```
str1="]}}{"QueryResult": {"APIMajor": "2", "APIMinor": "0", "Errors": [], "Warnings": [], "TotalResultCount": 272, "StartInd": 201, "PageSize": 200, "Results": ["

str2=", "
```

How do I replace `str1` in a JSON file with `str2` using shell?

Comment: Are you just trying to find & replace a string with string in another string? If so, I'd just give a go to `awk` and/or `sed`. Though it might be worth looking at some tools to deal with JSON: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955505/parsing-json-with-sed-and-awk

Comment: I tried sed but no luck..it is not replacing values, Here is code I am using                                                           str1="]}}{"\"QueryResult"\": {"\"_APIMajor"\": "\"2"\", "\"_APIMinor"\": "\"0"\", "\"Errors"\": [], "\"Warnings"\": [], "\"TotalResultCount"\": 272, "\"StartInd"\": 201, "\"PageSize"\": 200, "\"Results"\": ["

str2=", "



sed 's/${str1}/${str2}/g' -i filename